# How to compare a variable and a string through the diferent operator

Tags: java

I'm trying to verify if the input of the user is M or F (discarding every other letter), through the `!=` operator. I know this operator doesn't work, so I tried this:

```
System.out.println("Whats the gender?");
gender = read.next();
while ( !"M".equals(gender) || !"F".equals(gender))
      System.out.println("Rewrite your gender");
      gender = read.next();
}
```

however it doesn't verify. Doesn't matter what letter I input, it will always say to rewrite.

Comment: Say you input `F`. Is it not `M`? Likewise if you input `M` is it not `F`?

Comment: @GBlodgett my goal is: if the user inputs F or M, the program goes on, but if the user inputs any other string that is not F or M, the program asks them to rewrite the gender. I guess now my doud is clear.

Comment: I understand your goal; I'm trying to get you to see the logic error in your `while` condition

Comment: Try with this condition : while ( !("M".equals(gender) || "F".equals(gender)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition must be `!"M".equals(gender) && !"F".equals(gender)`